# How to find percent of certain values along columns in R dataframe

Tags: r

Suppose I have categorical values such as Yes or No in a number of columns, I want % of each column responding "yes" with a barplot. How I can be able to write code for R is shown below, showing what I need.

```
data <- read.table(text=
"Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
0   1   0   1
0   1   0   1
1   1   1   1
1   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
1   1   0   1", header=TRUE)
```

From the above table, I need % of each column responding yes (Yes=1, No=0) and with that percent values of all columns I want to visualize with a barplot in R. Please, guide me through the code.

As a beginner I am getting no idea at all. How to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please check the below output

```r
# Calculate the percentage of "yes" (1) for each column
percentage_yes <- colMeans(data) * 100

# Create a bar plot
barplot(percentage_yes, names.arg = colnames(data), ylab = "Percentage (%)", main = "Percentage of 'Yes' Responses")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I solved the same problem using for loop.   

`percent_yes <- list()  
for (i in colnames(data)) {  
  percent_yes[[i]] <- sum(data[[i]] == 1)/NROW(data[[i]])*100  
  percent_yes <- data.frame(percent_yes)  
}`